# Facebook Graph API getting data when user not logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, graph

I have this requirement of fetching facebook user information like friends count and other basic information and integrate to our website.

I currently use facebook graph to ask user to authorise, fetch information and store in my database.

When their say, friend count changes how do I update my database without asking user to trigger it manually.

Is there a special permission where i can fetch user data when he/she isnt logged in.

I have seen this somewhere but not sure of the permission.

Or does facebook have any feature of publishing information on subscription ?

I user ASP.net /C#.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook does have a subscription API, so you can subscribe to certain updates. Like a new friend. This way you don't have to keep polling or ask the user to update it.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime/

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to pull data when the user is not logged in you need to request the offline_access extended permission when having the user authorize

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/